# juniper ex4200 broadcast and multicast storm control

Tags: juniper-junos

i have applied the following configuration on my juniper ex4200-48p :

```
set ethernet-switching-options storm-control action-shutdown
set ethernet-switching-options storm-control interface ge-0/0/24.0 bandwidth 100
set ethernet-switching-options storm-control interface ge-0/0/24.0 multicast
set ethernet-switching-options storm-control interface all
```

so for now when the port switch multicast OR broadcast packet reach 100kbps then the port will be shutdown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ingress multicast, broadcast OR unknown unicast exceed 100kbps on ge-0/0/24.0 then the port will shut down.

For all other ports, broadcast and unknown unicast will be dropped if they exceed 80% (system default) of the interface speed (so 800Mbps).